# Android Chart how do i remove VERTICAL SIDE LINES ? tried everything

Tags: java, android, xml, mpandroidchart

[image]

I'm using MPAndroid Chart , I'm trying to remove these 2 lines and I don't know how.
In my code I already have these:

```
 chart.animateY(500);
        chart.invalidate();
        chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        chart.setDrawBorders(false);
        chart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(true);
        chart.setScaleEnabled(false);
        chart.setTouchEnabled(false);
        chart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);
        chart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);

        chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
        chart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
        chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);

        chart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
        chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
```

What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/axis-general/), setDrawAxisLine(boolean enabled): Set this to true if the line alongside the axis (axis-line) should be drawn or not.

In your case you could try with

`chart.getAxisLet().setDrawAxisLine(false)
chart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false)`

Hope it helps!

Comment: I've just tried 
``` chart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false); ``` 
as you suggested, but that's not the one , I still have those lines

Comment: since I am using `chart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);` , there shoudnt be anything in the chart related to X axis , perhaps it is not connected to the Xaxis?

Comment: it's possible, since from the docs, `setDrawAxisLine(boolean enabled): Set this to true if the line alongside the axis (axis-line) should be drawn or not.`. So maybe this is something not related at all with the axis as you say

Comment: Now that i see it, i have a similar project and i don't use `chart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false)`. Are you sure you need it?

Comment: Please could you try with this:
`chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false)`
`chart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false)`

Comment: `chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false) chart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false)`
that's it , it worked . Thank you very much :)